# Network error: connection refused after ForwardX11Trusted yes

Tags: ssh, x11, putty

I have an ubuntu server with opencv and cmake installed. My idea was to configure it so each time i run a program on the server i get the results on my local OS (windows 7) through Xming.

This morning everything was going great, i executed a program and my local machine detected it and opened an empty window. On the server, the execution returned me this error "GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed". I looked over the internet and i read that i could try writting "ForwardX11Trusted yes" in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, so i did it.

Now i cannot access the server. Putty shows me the "Network error: connection refused". As im not able to access the server i cannot reverse the last changes...

What can i do? Is it normal to put "ForwardX11Trusted yes" and then not be able to ssh connect anymore??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" suggests that the SSH server isn't running on the remote host. You may have failed to restart it properly, or there may be an error in `sshd_config` which prevented the server from restarting.

Comment: Yep, sshd_config was the problem. TY